# Creating an instance from AMI increases mongodb journal size to 3GB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS instance running in 1 machine. It has all the data files, server setup, mongodb database etc. I created a new AMI image, and then tried to launch an instance from this image. 
In the new machine as soon as created, the size of the mongodb journal started to increase from just 2.6MB in the original machine to 3.1GB in the new machine. (When the machine starts, and I ssh to the machine, I can see the size of the files increasing gradually and in 10 minutes it reaches around 3.1GB and stops.

I see that based on other answers, the 3.1GB is some magic number for journal files. My question is, why was it small in my original machine and why does it increase only after starting the instance.

I don't see 'smallFile' setting enabled in old or the new machine. There is no other changes. I have retried creating new images and new instances from these images multiple times.

Please let me know how to fix this issue? My total data file size is around 195MB only and the original journal file size is around 2.6MB.

Comment: When you create the AMI, are you doing it with the source instance running?  If so, are you selecting the "no reboot" option?

Comment: There source instance was running, but "no reboot" was turned off. So, the original server did get rebooted

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: In the new instance, is there a drawback of setting smallFiles option? Since my total data is small, and hardly has less than 500 writes per day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of things, you are using MMAPv1 and so are just seeing the [natural usage of the journal files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/#journaling-journal-files), where each journal file should be up to 1GB in size.  As stated in the docs, in normal conditions you should have up to 3 files and so up to 3GB of journal.

The fix for really small DBs that need to run on small VMs (like yours), is to enable the [smallFiles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.smallFiles) setting.  As already noted in SO, this should [not be a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613769/mongo-db-smallfiles-switch-drawbacks).

While you're at it, you might also want to check out this other answer when you switch: [Setting smallfiles option for controlling journaling doesn't control the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495587/setting-smallfiles-option-for-controlling-journaling-doesnt-control-the-size)

Comment: If so, why is the journal file size small in the original instance. I had not set the smallFile optin there either?

Comment: How does the load that you're running on your previous instance compare to the load that you're running on the new one?  Your original must be running no load to have journals that size.

Comment: Yes. There were no traffic to the new instance. Are you saying, a few reads/writes would be sufficient to bring down the journal file size back to normal?

Comment: That's the opposite of what I'd expect...  Are you sure nothing is happening on the new instance?